# DateField clearing itself every time object is edited

Tags: python, django, sqlite, orm

I have the following model:

```
class Day(models.Model):
day = models.DateField()
title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
votes = models.IntegerField(max_length=7)
last_vote = models.DateTimeField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

Whenever I edit it like this:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
day_to_vote_for.votes += 1
day_to_vote_for.last_vote = current_time
day_to_vote_for.save()
```

or whenever I edit through the admin control panel, it is reset to a blank field? Why? This doesn't happen with the Datetime field. How do I fix it?

People need to be able to specify dates other than now. So auto_now_add won't work. It's just clearing for no reason.

Comment: Change to models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True) and then just update without adding a current_time.

Comment: Nope. Still getting IntegrityError at /day/2/vote/

Days_day.day may not be NULL

Comment: That means that you have some rows in your database that don't have a value. Try to create again your database if you don't have a lot of info there or use Django South to fill those missing values.

Comment: I deleted my database file and recreated it, that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass auto_now=True if you want the field to be updated with current timestamp whenever you save it or use auto_now_add=True to save the timestamp when the object was actually created.

Comment: Why doesn't DateTimeField have the same problem?

Comment: Still getting IntegrityError at /day/1/vote/

Days_day.day may not be NULL

Comment: it looks like part of your problem lies in current_time = datetime.datetime.now that's a funny way of doing that. I agree with the auto_now=True